# "Inappropriate blocking method call" when one StringBuilder appends another

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reactive-programming, project-reactor, stringbuilder

Why does IntelliJ IDEA show the warning "Inappropriate blocking method call" when one `StringBuilder` appends another?

```java
public Mono<String> doSomethingReactive() {
    final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("hello");
    final StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("world");
    sb1.append(sb2); // This append() causes warning "Inappropriate blocking method call"
    sb1.append(sb2.toString()); // ... but this append() is OK :)
    return Mono.just(sb1.toString());
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's IntelliJ being special. If we were talking about `StringBuffer` that would be different, but `StringBuilder` doesn't have any blocking code AFAIK.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I created an issue in the JetBrains tracking tool: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA, unless someone comes with a reasonable explanation. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282947

Answer (score 0):

I think it is blocking so perhaps that is why intelliJ is complaining. Since you are creating the Mono at the end of the method everything that comes before that is executed before or outside of the Mono flow. It defeats the purpose of a reactive flow. If I put the Mono at the top then no warning:

```
public Mono<String> doSomethingReactive() {
    return Mono.just(new StringBuilder("hello"))
            .map(sb1 -> {
                StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("world");
                sb1.append(sb2);
                sb1.append(sb2.toString());
                return sb1.toString();
            });
}
```

In this case only the creation of the first StringBuilder is executed outside of the Mono flow.

Also, mind you, I think intelliJ may think that `sb1.append(sb2)` is calling Object::toString() which may well be blocking when it is caching the class name in the VM whereas `sb1.append(sb2.toString())` is called StringBuilder::toString() which may not do any blocking.